# ¿Dónde escribir código en los fragment?

Tags: java, android

Intentando escribir mi código en un fragment en Android Studio no logro poder hacer que mi acciones se ejecuten tampoco estoy seguro en donde escribirlos, En esta imagen muestro al asignar la id de la imagen luego que la ImageView contenga la imagen pero sucede un error, hay tan poca información sobre esto...

Edito: Al parecer el error sucede al asiganar el id supongo que en el lugar donde inserte el codigo es un ¿lugar incorrecto?

[image]

Comment: Para empezar, corre la aplicación en el depurador (debug) y revisa si tienes una excepción útil. Luego sería amable de colocar código como texto (indentado 4 espacios) en vez de una captura de pantalla :) Bienvenido a SOes.

Comment: el código esta bien el problema es que no tengo claro en donde empezar a escribirlo,  al escribirlo en un lugar equivocado produce el error..

Comment: publica tu código y no lo pongas como imagen, coloca el de tu layout y tu clase.

Comment: Todo mi  código son esas 3 lineas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_galeria, container, false);
```

inicia una variable para que puedas acceder al `View` de tu fragmento..

```
ImageView imageview;
imageview = (Imageview)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewGaleria)
...
```

y retornas la variable `view`

Comment: Gracias fue muy útil tu respuesta